# Displaying a single rank in MySQL table

Tags: sql, mysql, ranking, rank, analytic-functions

I have a table called 'highscores' that looks like this.

```
id      udid       name       score
1       1111       Mike       200
2       3333       Joe        300
3       4444       Billy      50
4       0000       Loser      10
5       DDDD       Face       400
```

Given a specific udid, I want to return the rank of that row by their score value.

i.e. if udid given = 0000, I should return 5.

Any idea how to write this query for a MySQL database?

Answer (score 7):

MySQL doesn't have any analytic/ranking functionality, but you can use a variable to artificially create a rank value:

```
  SELECT t.id,
         t.udid,
         t.name,
         t.score,
         @rownum := @rownum + 1 AS rank
    FROM HIGHSCORES t
    JOIN (SELECT @rownum := 0) r
ORDER BY t.score DESC
```

In order to see what rank is associated with `UDID` "0000", use:

```
SELECT MAX(x.rank) AS rank
  FROM (SELECT t.id,
               t.udid,
               t.name,
               t.score,
               @rownum := @rownum + 1 AS rank
          FROM HIGHSCORES t
          JOIN (SELECT @rownum := 0) r
      ORDER BY t.score DESC) x
 WHERE x.udid = '0000'
```

Need the `MAX` for if the user has multiple high score values.  Alternately, you could not use `MAX` and use `ORDER BY rank LIMIT 1`.

Comment: ahh thanks, there is only 1 entry per udid, I take care of that in my php script.

also, I'm a little knew to this.  So how do the two blocks work together.  Do I put them in the same query? Or right after each other?

Comment: @MichaelInno: If you are only checking for a specific users rank, you only need to use the second query.  Replace the `'0000'` with whatever `udid` you are looking for.

Comment: This will give you different ranks for users with the same score.

Comment: @Josef: Yes - most don't want ties to have the same rank value.

Answer (score 1):

To reiterate OMG's excellent answer which is the general case of multiple high scores per udid, here's the query based on the precondition of exactly one entry per udid:

```
SELECT rank
FROM
   (SELECT @rownum := @rownum + 1 AS rank, score, udid
    FROM highscores
    JOIN (SELECT @rownum := 0) r
    ORDER BY highscores.score DESC) x
WHERE x.udid = '0000'
```